# Call to SSPI Failed C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

[image]I get this output from my output:

> Connecting to 192.168.3.116:21
>   220 ProFTPD Server (Debian)
>   AUTH TLS
>   220 AUTH TLS Successful
>   Unable to connect

Exception:

> 2/20/2020 11:18 AM Message: A call to SSPI failed, see inner
>   exception. InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>   (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they
>   do not possess a common algorithm    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at Hani.Utilities.SslClient.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Users\Specter\Documents\PlusFTP\Utilities\SslClient.cs:line 36

Here is the cs file code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hani.Utilities
{
    static class SslClient
    {
        /*public class SampleEventArgs
        {
            public SampleEventArgs(string s)
            {
                Text = s;
            }
            public String Text { get; private set; } // readonly
        } */

        internal delegate void ValidateCertificateHandler(object sender, 
            X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors);
        internal static event ValidateCertificateHandler OnValidateCertificate;

        internal static void ValidateCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, 
            X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (OnValidateCertificate != null)
                new ValidateCertificateHandler(OnValidateCertificate)
                      (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors);
        }

        internal static async Task<SslStream> ConnectAsync(Stream s, 
                    string server, SslProtocols prot)
        {
            try
            {
                X509CertificateCollection clientCertColl = new X509CertificateCollection();
                SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(s, false, 
                    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(validate), null);
                await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(server, 
                          clientCertColl, prot, false);
                return sslStream;
            }
            catch (Exception exp) { ExceptionHelper.Log(exp); }
            return null;
        }

        private static bool validate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, 
                X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                ValidateCertificate(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors);
                //InfoMsg("Certificate error: " + tmpResponsed, MessageType.Error);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, my edge browser wasn't letting me add the remaining parts of my issue/code

Comment: It looks like the important part of the message is `The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm`. What .NET version is your code targeting? It is possible you need to use a newer .NET version to enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. You may also need to specify the desired security protocols before starting a connection. For example: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I updated your question with some formatting... hopefully you are able to get some helpful answers/comments to resolve your issue.

Comment: i`m targeting 4.8

Comment: Are you using TLS or SSL?  Your output says TLS but your code is SSL.

Comment: SSL I know the output says TLS, i've switch modes to SSL/TLS and vice versa and I still get it regardless